# How to group a field in table only untill it changes value (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the Following Table 'ProductTable'

```
Product   | Series | Date  
  aaa     | a1     | 2016-05-17 08:02:54.960 
  aaa     | a1     | 2016-05-17 08:03:54.960
  aaa     | a1     | 2016-05-17 08:04:54.960
  bbb     | b1     | 2016-05-17 08:05:54.960
  bbb     | b1     | 2016-05-17 08:06:54.960
  aaa     | a1     | 2016-05-17 08:07:54.960
  aaa     | a1     | 2016-05-17 08:08:54.960
```

I tried few steps from google and found something called `row_number() over` but failed to get the exact results using it as I am new to SQL SERVER.I want the result to be like this -- >

```
Product   | Series | Qty |  Cumml.
  aaa     | a1     | 3   |    3
  bbb     | b1     | 2   |    5
  aaa     | a1     | 2   |    7
```

How to do grouping of this nature? Please Help ....

Comment: As I see it is a simple group by Product, isn't it?

Comment: Not quite - its ordered by the date column and aaa appears twice

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No because first `aaa` and second will be united

Comment: Oh I see now, @Caleth

Comment: Nope ! If i do Group by Product i wont get the result as i have shown i would get only 2 rows in result showing `aaa` with qty 5 and `bbb` with qty 2 isnt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard islands solution with some window aggregate function for cumulative sum:

```
DECLARE @p TABLE
    (
      Product CHAR(3) ,
      Date DATETIME
    )
INSERT  INTO @p
VALUES  ( 'aaa', '2016-05-17 08:02:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa', '2016-05-17 08:03:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa', '2016-05-17 08:04:54.960' ),
        ( 'bbb', '2016-05-17 08:05:54.960' ),
        ( 'bbb', '2016-05-17 08:06:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa', '2016-05-17 08:07:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa', '2016-05-17 08:08:54.960' );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY date )
                        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Date ) AS rn
               FROM     @p
             )
    SELECT  rn ,
            product ,
            COUNT(*) AS Cnt,
            SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(Date) ) AS Cumul
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY rn ,
            product
    ORDER BY Cumul
```

Output:

```
rn  product Cnt Cumul
0   aaa     3   3
3   bbb     2   5
2   aaa     2   7
```

Comment: but how to show the individual qty and also in the order in which they are originally, means aaa then bbb and then again aaa .

Comment: Order By Min / Max Date gives the original ordering

Comment: yes its correct.Thankyou Sir .. Does this type of grouping has a name in SQL slang ?

Comment: Gaps and islands solutions. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  Product Varchar(5) ,
  Series Varchar(5),
  Date DATETIME
)
INSERT  INTO #Temp
VALUES  ( 'aaa','a1', '2016-05-17 08:02:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa','a1','2016-05-17 08:03:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa','a1', '2016-05-17 08:04:54.960' ),
        ( 'bbb','b1', '2016-05-17 08:05:54.960' ),
        ( 'bbb','b1', '2016-05-17 08:06:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa','a1', '2016-05-17 08:07:54.960' ),
        ( 'aaa','a1', '2016-05-17 08:08:54.960' )
;WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Date )
                    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Date ) AS rn
           FROM     #Temp
         )
SELECT
        Product ,Series,
        COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY Product ) AS Cnt,
        SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(Date) ) AS cumml
FROM    cte
GROUP BY rn ,Product,Series
Order BY cumml
```